# How to load a file contained in a package

Tags: ros, load

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say I have a file with stored information. I don't want to put the absolute path, neither do I want to roscd mypackage before executing my node so that the file can be found.
Is there an elegant way of doing that on both Python and C++?

If it is not possible, how can I then solve the problem when using roslaunch, because then the file is not found anymore even when change my directory to the packages directory before launching.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173970/how-to-load-a-file-contained-in-a-package/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-06-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-06-19**:
Excellent question! I usually set the project source dir as define in CMakeLists.txt ( set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DLOCATION=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}) ) and then use this define (LOCATION) in my code to locate the files. --> Works but what would be the proper way to do that??

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-06-19**:
is {PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} a general flag recognized by CMake or do you replace it by the global path? In case of the latter option this doesn't fully solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be interested in the [roslib C++ API](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/roslib/html/c++/). Especially the section on [packages](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/roslib/html/c++/namespaceros_1_1package.html).

To get the fully qualified path to a package (from there it should be easy enough to navigate to the actual file) you should probably use [ros::package::getPath(const std::string& package_name)](http://docs.ros.org/api/roslib/html/c++/namespaceros_1_1package.html#ae9470dd201aa4e66abb833e710d812a4).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-06-30**:
I think this is the right way to do it. Thanks !
I also found this tutorial that describes how to use the API for both C++ and Python
http://wiki.ros.org/Packages#Client_Library_Support